# Named slide with \printindex

Tags: imakeidx

```latex
\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \let\item\par  % definitions for subitem etc
    \let\subitem\par
    \let\subsubitem\par
}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex
```

I need to named the slides with `\printindex`, but I don't know how. The parameters of `\makeindex` don't work.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}




\usepackage{multicol}


\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
    \let\subitem\par
    \let\subsubitem\par
}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{apple}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Algorithm}
\end{frame}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure what's the use for an index in `beamer`. Can you please make a short, but complete example?

Comment: @egreg Okey ,I did it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just insert `\printindex` in a frame.

```
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
    \let\subitem\par
    \let\subsubitem\par
}{}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Apples}
\index{apple}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Algorithms}
\index{Algorithm}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\indexname}
\let\clearpage\relax % avoid empty frames
\printindex
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks .But if i have 100 indexes , it isn`t work

Comment: @re1nex You can use `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]`

Comment: @egred I have some problem . I have two empty slides in begin when i write \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Предметный указатель}
\printindex
\end{frame}

Comment: @egred please help,I try find information about it ,but i couldn`t find something

Comment: @re1nex I added the trick.

Comment: @egred excuse me ,can you look this , please https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484965/indents-and-costomize-printidex

Comment: @egred , excuse me , is it possible named only the first slide ?