# Indents and customize \printidex

Tags: beamer, indexing, imakeidx

```
\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \let\item\par  % definitions for subitem etc
    \let\subitem\par
    \let\subsubitem\par
}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex
```

I need to do indents between left side of slide and subitems ,and do it with subsubitems,like :

```
algorithm - item
   search - subitem
      depth first , -subsubitem
      breadth fist), -subsubitem
```

And I need to do that subitem and subsubitem don`t go to the new frame, e.g. New frame begin by the item

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}




\usepackage{multicol}


\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
    \let\subitem\par
    \let\subsubitem\par
}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{apple}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Algorithm}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\indexname}
\let\clearpage\relax % avoid empty frames
\printindex
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define properly `\subitem` and `\subsubitem`.

Please, also check carefully the changes I made.

1. `utf8x` is not recommended; use `utf8` (or nothing at all if you use a recent TeX distribution).
2. the `latexsym` package exists only for back compatibility
3. there's no need to load `epstopdf`
4. you miss `{}` at the end of `\renewenvironment{theindex}`

```latex
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
  \def\subitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{2em}\ignorespaces}%
  \def\subsubitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{4em}\ignorespaces}%
  \def\indexspace{}%
}{}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\index{apple}\index{apple!a}\index{apple!a!b}
\index{Algorithm}\index{Algorithm!a}\index{Algorithm!a!b}
\index{aa}\index{aaa}\index{aaaa}\index{aaaaa}\index{aaaaaa}
\index{aaaaaaa}\index{aaaaaaaa}\index{aaaaaaaaa}
\index{aaaaaaaaaa}\index{aaaaaaaaaaa}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{\indexname}
\let\clearpage\relax % avoid empty frames
\printindex
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much , but when I use \nobreak \printindex doesn`t show some indexes ,for example when I have \item and many \subitems ,it will be the last frame when I use \nobreak ,what can I do with it ?

Comment: @re1nex If you have too many subitems, they can't go in one frame, can they?

Comment: and early I do two cols like \renewenvironment{theindex}{%
 \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
 \let\subitem\par
 \let\subsubitem\par
 \begin{multicols}{2}
 }{\end{multicols}}
\makeatletter ,how can I do it now ?

Comment: No , they can`t,I think maybe do two cols for they

Comment: What do \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% ?

Comment: @re1nex That's just for better safety; probably not necessary.

Comment: Okey ,thanks) But what about 2 cols ?

Comment: @re1nex Sorry, I don't think you can do that in beamer.

Comment: May be exist another way to named the \printindex slides ?

Comment: The ONE INDEX FRAME ONLY can be multicol {2} {3} or {+} columns but depending on \printindex font size may not allow for as many sub index entries as you may require If you want a longer list it has to roll into multiple (unlimited) frames as per this answer