# Miktex \printindex doesn`t work

Tags: beamer, miktex, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I use MiKTeX 2.9 and use{imakeidx } for doing list of indexes in beamer.
but I have the message in log:
No file "DM2019_7 (2)".ind.
[103

]
In texstudio it works .
Please help.

Example :

```
    \documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}




\usepackage{multicol}


\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
    \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
    \let\subitem\par
    \let\subsubitem\par
}
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{apple}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Algorithm}
\end{frame}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the OLD question that had spaces and needed Makindex to be run externally HERE the SPACES ARE RESPECTED AS VALID it is a VERY POOR choice however it WILL automatically run makeindex using MiKTeX and Texmaker if configured properly using just default installations. What is apparently on occasion confusing re1nex is after a successful  run there are two blank pages (see their other question) which I had answered here since this is in effect a duplicate of that question which does not have an answer hence was not addressed and this question asked again.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you forgot to run `makeindex` via command line in the directory where the BIB file resides?

This command must be executed in order to generate the index files from the BIB file.

Comment: How I can do this ?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing

Comment: Texmaker does it automatically NO NEED to run it externally on its own.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for your comment, I always used MikTeX and experienced some issues myself some time ago until I ran makeindex.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you ensure you navigate to the folder with DM2019_7 (2).tex and in the address bar type cmd (to open a console window)

I get no errors by running

```
pdflatex "DM2019_7 (2).tex"
pdflatex "DM2019_7 (2).tex"
makeindex "DM2019_7 (2).tex"
pdflatex "DM2019_7 (2).tex"
```

finally entering

```
"DM2019_7 (2).pdf"
```

command opens viewer with 3 pages
Page one looks blank but has an invisible placeholder for the \index apple
Page two also looks blank, since that's what you asked for with start frame index item >end frame so has an invisible entry for Algorithm.
Page three is the index of the two previous pages with index words Algorithm, 2 and apple, 1

**FROM Texmaker** and many expert editors you will be warned to NOT save files with spaces in the filename.
 This will not stop compile working in this case, however I would suggest you listen to that warning and others about underscores and not to use odd or accented characters just for the habit of not having to keep sorting issues about filenames later.
Thus I recommend you change your filename to DM2019-7-2.tex

Texmaker should produce the same results as above if you run **Compile (quick build) 2 times** First run with warnings is normal while it tries to resolve all the background links then the consolidation run should generally be error free.

[image]

Same Notes [from previous answer by JouleV] ([Indents and customize \printidex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484965/indents-and-customize-printidex))

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer} %Remove mathserif as out of date method see the warning messages and documentation
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} %1. `utf8x` is not recommended; use `utf8` (or nothing at all if you use a recent TeX distribution). 
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{PTSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% \usepackage{epstopdf} %3. There's no need to load `epstopdf`
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm} %2. the `latexsym` package exists only for back compatibility .
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\renewenvironment{theindex}{% Define properly \subitem and \subsubitem.
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \let\item\par   % definitions for subitem etc
  \def\subitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{2em}\ignorespaces}%Define properly \subitem and \subsubitem.
  \def\subsubitem{\par\nobreak\hspace*{4em}\ignorespaces}%Define properly \subitem and \subsubitem.
  \def\indexspace{}%
}{} %4. You missed {} at the end of \renewenvironment{theindex}{}  
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}
\makeatother
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
\index{apple}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\index{Algorithm}
\end{frame}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: It work in texstudio , but in miktex it isn`t work

Comment: I am using TexMaker

Comment: To try and understand why Texmaker is not working for you In Texmaker go to `Tools` `Open Terminal` at the prompt type and enter `Where $path:makeindex` also `Where /r \ makeindex` compare the 2 answers ARE they the same ?